# Flyway: multiple databases with same migration version number errors out

Tags: flyway

Baselining two databases on the same server, with each having their own starting  migration script numbered `V2__`, I get the error below:

`flyway:baseline` produces the error

`Found more than one migration with version 2`

Each migration script lives in its own migration dir: `db/migration/db1, db/migration/db2`

Did I miss a config, or is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

I learned its not possible to migrate multiple databases using just property files.  Its only possible by triggering the migration with Java code, so I wired up a bean to handle this:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywaySlaveInitializer {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    @PostConstruct
    Flyway flyway() {
        String datasource = env.getProperty("flyway.url");
        String[] schemas = env.getProperty("flyway.schemas").split(",");
        String[] schemaLocations = env.getProperty("flyway.locations").split(",");

        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

        for (int schema = 0; schema < schemas.length; schema++) {
            flyway.setDataSource(datasource + "/" + schemas[schema], "root", "root");
            flyway.setSchemas(schemas[schema]);
            flyway.setLocations("db/migration/" + schemaLocations[schema]);
            flyway.migrate();
        }

        return flyway;
    }
}
```